# Questionable email from discord

Tags: account-security, gmail, email-spoofing

I got a gmail from discord saying a new account had been registered and prompting me to click a verification link. Weirdly, I never made that account, and I already had a discord account under my gmail. Of course, I didn't click the verification link. I checked and was luckily able to log into my discord account, and changed the password for good measure. When I examined the email, it seems the message was sent to the wrong person. For the sake of this making sense, I'm johndoe123@gmail.com and the email details say it got sent to john.doe123@gmail.com ... also, I checked and the sender seems to be a legitimate email under the discord.com domain.

**What's afoot here? Is it something malicious? Is it just that the gmail account doesn't exist so it got redirected to mine because it was the most similar?**

Comment: Someone might have simply supplied the wrong email address

Answer (score 1):

With Gmail, 'The Dots Don't Matter'.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en.

So, mail sent to john.doe123@gmail.com will be routed to the same mailbox as johndoe123@gmail.com.

As to why this happened in the first place - it could be that someone is trying to pull-off a variation of [this scam](https://jameshfisher.com/2018/04/07/the-dots-do-matter-how-to-scam-a-gmail-user/), to create a Discord account (possibly for fraudulent purposes) under your email address.

Comment: Just to clarify for him, what exactly should he do in this situation? Just ignore the email?

Comment: @CipherVisor Thanks for asking this question.  Yes, he should ignore the verification email if he did not create an account under that address that it was sent to.